# documenting imports in Python

Tags: python, django

So imagine I have a Django 1.9 application with many models.

Inside `admin.py` I import my models, but I want to stick to the 80 character limit. What is the best practice for something like this?

For example

```
from .models import app_name_student, app_name_teacher, app_name_employment, app_name_grade, app_name_subject, app_name_activity
```

Is this the best solution or are there better solutions that I'm not aware of? Typically, I would do this

```
from .models import app_name_student, app_name_teacher, app_name_employment
from .models import app_name_grade, app_name_subject, app_name_activity
```

Otherwise, there probably is a framework/standards that I am not aware of...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there is nothing wrong with what you have - you can and should split up imports.

However, [as per pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) (the Python style guide) you can use `( )`:

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
>   line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
>   can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
>   parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
>   for line continuation.

That would result in code like:

```
from .models import (
   app_name_student,
   app_name_teacher,
   ...
   ...
)
```

Although it may raise a a few eyebrows as its not a common use of `( )`; most developers prefer multiple import lines.

Avoid the temptation to do `from .models import *`.

Comment: First, totally agree with you to not use `from .models import *`. Shoutout to all who use Java and Python and similar languages. Thanks!